# Using Java streams to merge a pair of `int` arrays

Tags: java, arrays, merge, java-stream

[This page](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-java) shows how to combine two arrays of `Integer` objects into an array of `Object` objects.

```
Integer[] firstArray = new Integer[] { 10 , 20 , 30 , 40 };
Integer[] secondArray = new Integer[] { 50 , 60 , 70 , 80 };
Object[] merged = 
        Stream
        .of( firstArray , secondArray )
        .flatMap( Stream :: of )
        .toArray()
;
```

> Arrays.toString( merged ): [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]

➥ Is there a way to use Java streams to concatenate a pair of arrays of primitive `int` values rather than objects?

```
int[] a = { 10 , 20 , 30 , 40 };
int[] b = { 50 , 60 , 70 , 80 };
int[] merged = … ?
```

I realize using Java streams may not be the most efficient way to go. But I am curious about the interplay of primitives and Java streams.

I am aware of [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) but cannot see how to use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## `IntStream.concat`

Transform each array into an `IntStream`. Then call [`IntStream.concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#concat(java.util.stream.IntStream,java.util.stream.IntStream)) to combine.

Lastly, generate an array of `int` by calling [`IntStream::toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray()).

```java
int[] a = { 10 , 20 , 30 , 40 };
int[] b = { 50 , 60 , 70 , 80 };

int[] merged = IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(a), IntStream.of(b)).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(merged));
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/KBNf7z).

Output:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
```

Tip: To sort the results, call [`.sorted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sorted()) before the `.toArray()`. As seen [running on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/pmfYAS).

Comment: This seems to be the most efficient of all these interesting Answers, as it is the only one to avoid the overhead of [auto-boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). Anyone, please correct me if I am misunderstanding the boxing involved in such work.

Comment: @BasilBourque quick test: put a breakpoint at [`Integer#valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)), run debugger and see if it is triggered. It did not:) on openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14

Comment: @BasilBourque Just a side note, that [the other variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54864499/1746118) is still slightly better [than this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54864606/1746118) in one way.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way, using [`Stream::flatMapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt(java.util.function.Function)).

```
int[] a = { 10 , 20 , 30 , 40 };
int[] b = { 50 , 60 , 70 , 80 };
int[] merged = Stream.of(a,b).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of)
                .toArray();
```

Comment: Interesting. I had not noticed [`Stream::flatMapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt(java.util.function.Function)). But I suspect the [Answer by caco3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61297134/642706) would avoid auto-boxing and therefore be more performant.

Comment: Yep.  And I forgot about `IntStream.concat()`.  One of these days I may get this all down.

Answer (score 3):

**You could use something like that if you want to work with `merged`:**

```
Integer[] firstArray = new Integer[] {10, 20, 30, 40};
Integer[] secondArray = new Integer[] {50, 60, 70, 80};
Object[] merged = Stream.of(firstArray, secondArray).flatMap(Stream::of).toArray();

int[] ints = Arrays.stream(merged).mapToInt(o -> Integer.parseInt(o.toString())).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
```

**Output:**

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `concat` method of `Stream` to merge them and use `boxed` method of `IntStream` to convert it to `Stream`.

```java
int[] firstArray = new int[]{10, 20, 30, 40};
int[] secondArray = new int[]{50, 60, 70, 80};
Object[] merged =
        Stream
              .concat(Arrays.stream(firstArray).boxed(), Arrays.stream(secondArray).boxed())
              .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(merged)); // [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
```

Comment: Worthy of an up-vote, but it looks like the [Answer by caco3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61297134/642706) does much the same while avoiding the overhead of auto-boxing.